# What are some halachically proper fast-day greetings?

Tags: halacha, fast-days, tisha-bav, social-convention

Considering that greeting someone during the Tisha B'Av fast day is prohibited, is there a proper way according to halacha to greet somone before the day?

For example, to say "have an easy fast".

Comment: It's generally forbidden to greet people on Tisha Bav

Comment: Is there a source for that?

Comment: Shulchan Aruch 554:20

Comment: Not a greeting, but I like to say: "May Tisha B'Av never bring us another catastrophe".

Answer (score 1):

I just got wished to have a meaningful fast. This is elegant, in the spirit of the day, and something I've heard often.

Have a meaningful fast!

Comment: Is this written anywhere? I'm a bit wary of the epistemological validity of "heard often". People don't always know the proper way to go about things.

Answer (score 1):

As a friend just explained to me in the name of his late Father, A"H, on Yom Kippur it is appropriate to say have an easy fast.  But it is not appropriate to say so on Tisha B"Av as we are supposed to feel ourselves in mourning.

Comment: As much as I respect that, I'm looking for a source in writing.  If it exists...